# Cannot Lock, Shutdown, Or Reboot Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, reboot, microsoft-surface, lock

I have no idea how to reproduce this but this has happened several times over the last few weeks and now twice today.

- ctrl+alt+delete does nothing
- Start Menu -> Power -> Shutdown does
  nothing
- Start Menu -> Power -> Restart does nothing
- WindowKey+L does
  nothing (should lock computer)
- PowerShell Restart-Computer does
  nothing
- PowerShell Stop-Computer does nothing

I have shutdown every application and tried all of the above again. Nothing. I have tried restarting Windows Explorer. No luck. Force shutdown by holding the power button for about 10 seconds just causes the screen to flash (the same behavior as if you tried to do a force shutdown during a Windows update). The only thing that works is the Super Force Shutdown (I have no idea what this is called) - hold the power button and volume up button for about 15 seconds.

I'm running Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.16299 Build 16299 on a Surface Book.

Has anybody seen anything like this before?

Comment: Have you checked for updated firmwares and drivers for the device?

Comment: When did it start, precisely?  Look in Event Viewer for the unexpected shutdown event (6008 I think) and correlate it with your holding down power button.  Then you can correlate to the times you've run Windows Update, installed other programs, or made other changes to the PC.  It may be useful to install a graphing temperature monitor to see the CPU temperature.

Comment: What if under Safe Mode?